# Can we provide fxLayoutGap value in varibale?

Tags: angular-flex-layout

I need to provide fxLayoutGap value in variable instead of directly number. Below code for your reference:

ex: fivepix = '5px';

`<div fxLayoutGap="5px"></div>`

`<div fxLayoutGap="fivepix"></div>`

Like above can we declare it?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You must initialize a value in your **component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.fivepix = "5px"
}
```

Then use Template Expressions in your **component.html** like this:

```
<div [fxLayoutGap]="fivepix"></div>
```